# R to change the values in html form and scrape web data

Tags: html, r, web, scrape, rvest

I would like to scrape the historical weather data from this page http://www.weather.gov.sg/climate-historical-daily.

I am using the code given in this link [Using r to navigate and scrape a webpage with drop down html forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257579/using-r-to-navigate-and-scrape-a-webpage-with-drop-down-html-forms).

However, I am not able to get the data probably due to change in structure of the page. In the code from the above link `pgform <-html_form(pgsession)[[3]]` was used to change the values of the form. I was not able to find a similar form in my case.

```
url <- "http://www.weather.gov.sg/climate-historical-daily"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgsource <- read_html(url)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)
```

result in my case

```
> pgform
[[1]]
<form> 'searchform' (GET http://www.weather.gov.sg/)
<button submit> '<unnamed>
<input text> 's':
```

Comment: That's just getting the search box, not the actual controls, which are not in a `<form>` tag and thus can't be handled by `html_form`. You'd probably need RSelenium. The page does have nice CSV download links, though, which seem to follow a pattern and could thus probably be downloaded directly with `download.file` provided you can figure out which ones you need.

Comment: Thank you and I agree with you that the page has download links. But I need data for last 3 years data, for all the stations listed in the dropdown. I thought if I can figure out this part I can write a loop to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the page has a CSV download button and the links it provides follow a pattern, you can generate and download a set of URLs. You'll need a set of the station IDs, which you can scrape from the dropdown itself:

```
library(rvest)

page <- 'http://www.weather.gov.sg/climate-historical-daily' %>% read_html()

station_id <- page %>% html_nodes('button#cityname + ul a') %>% 
    html_attr('onclick') %>%    # If you need names, grab the `href` attribute, too.
    sub(".*'(.*)'.*", '\\1', .)
```

which can then be put into `expand.grid` with the months and years to generate all the necessary combinations:

```
df <- expand.grid(station_id, 
                  month = sprintf('%02d', 1:12),
                  year = 2014:2016)
```

(Note if you want 2017 data, you'll need to construct those separately and `rbind` so as not to construct months that haven't happened yet.)

The combinations can then be `paste0`ed into URLs:

```
urls <- paste0('http://www.weather.gov.sg/files/dailydata/DAILYDATA_', 
               df$station_id, '_', df$year, df$month, '.csv')
```

which can be `lapply`ed across to download all the files:

```
# Warning! This will download a lot of files! Make sure you're in a clean directory.    
lapply(urls, function(url){download.file(url, basename(url), method = 'curl')})
```