# Unable to download a file with rvest/httr after submitting search form

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

This seems like a simple problem but I've been struggling with it for a few days. This is a minimum working example rather than the actual problem:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540105/download-csv-file-from-webpage-after-submitting-form-from-dropdown-using-rvest-p) seemed similat but I was unable to use the answer to solve my problem.

In a browser, I go to [this url](https://secure.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/PublicRegister/Search/), and click on [Search] (no need to make any choices from the lists), and then on [Download Results] (choosing, for example, the Xlsx option). The file then downloads.

To automate this in R I have tried:

```
library(rvest)

url1 <- "https:/secure.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/PublicRegister/Search"
sesh1 <- html_session(url1)
form1    <-html_form(sesh1)[[1]]
subform <- submit_form(sesh1, form1)
```

Using Chrome Developer tools I find the url being used to initiate the download, so I try:

```
url2 <- "https:/secure.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/PublicRegister/Search/Download"
res <- GET(url = url2, query = list(format = "xlsx"))
```

However this does not download the file:

```
> res$content
  raw(0)
```

I also tried

```
download.file(url = paste0(url2, "?format=xlsx") , destfile = "down.xlsx", mode = "wb")
```

But this downloads nothing:

```
> Content type '' length 0 bytes
> downloaded 0 bytes
```

Note that, in the browser, pasting `url2` and adding the `format` query does initiate the download (after doing the search from `url1`)

I thought that I should somehow be using the session info from the initial code block to do the download, but so far I can't see how.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: you need to use `jump_to`

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there and your intuition is correct about using the session info.

You just need to use `rvest::jump_to` to navigate to the second url and then write it to disk:

```
library(rvest)

url1 <- "https:/secure.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/PublicRegister/Search"
sesh1 <- html_session(url1)
form1    <-html_form(sesh1)[[1]]
subform <- submit_form(sesh1, form1)

url2 <- "https://secure.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/PublicRegister/Search/Download"

#### The above is your original code - below is the additional code you need:

download <- jump_to(subform, paste0(url2, "?format=xlsx"))
writeBin(download$response$content, "down.xlsx")
```